# How to get the names of directories in the internal storage in a class that extends fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, internal-storage

I created a directory in the internal storage called `lists`, which contains directories.

Now I'm trying to get the directory names (in a class that extends the `fragment` class) to display them in a listview. I already now how to get the names of files out of the internal storage, but I can't get the names of directories.

How can I do this?

Comment: your question is not clear, please update your question with more detail